# Understanding object creation and comparison in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I wonder how object comparison is made on CoreData entities.
Supposing I have two entities, with a to-many relationship.

```
EntityA {
 prop1
 entityB <-- to-many relationship
}

EntityB {
 .... properties
 entityA <-- one-to-one relationship
}
```

Supposing I want to retrieve an entity with a certain prop1 with a NSPredicate, for simplicity let's say there only one EntityA satisfying such criteria:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"prop1=%@",x];
EntityA *entityA = //execute fetch
```

Now I want to retrieve all EntityB passing entityA as criteria:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"EntityA=%@",entityA];
EntityB *entityB = //execute fetch
EntityA *parentA = entityB.entityA;
```

At this point considering that I didn't override any method, but EntityA and EntityB just extend NSManagedObject, what would be the result of this statement ?

```
if(entityA==parentA) NSLog(@"YES");
else NSLog("NO");
```

In case of "YES", why such result ? And how many objects I have in the same execution ? For example using any persistence layer the I know of in Java would result in two distinct objects and the comparison is "YES" only if I override the equals method of relevant classes and implement some logic in there, such as:

```
if(objA.getRegistrationNumber()==objA.getRegistrationNumber()) return true;
```

In this case I wonder if CoreData is doing some kind of object caching and reusing.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Managed objects are identified using objectIDs:  if your two of your "objects" actually represent the same managed object, their objectIDs will be the same.  You can determine this by:

```
[[objectA objectID] isEqual:[objectB objectID]]
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/Reference/NSManagedObjectID.html

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C `==` would check if entityB and A point to the same object in memory. You would want to use the `isEqual:` method to do the comparison.
I think that if you did `isEqual:` method it would return YES and if your did `==` it would most likely return NO.